Assistance Required: Integration of Ubuntu Landscape with Keycloak
We are currently working on integrating Ubuntu Landscape with Keycloak for OpenID authentication. Despite our efforts, we have encountered challenges during testing and validation, particularly with the configuration in /etc/landscape/service.conf.
Below is the configuration we attempted:
[openid]  
enabled = true  
provider-url = https://54.220.18.25/realms/LandscapeRealm  # Keycloak server  
client-id = landscape  
client-secret = SbN***ZB  
redirect-uri = https://54.247.5.231/login/*  # Landscape server  
While we suspect the callback URL might be:
https://<LANDSCAPE_SERVER_URL>/openid/callback,
this detail is not explicitly available in the official Ubuntu Landscape documentation, leading to ambiguity during the setup.

The testing and validation of this integration have not been successful, and we suspect there may be missing or misconfigured components in the setup process.
We kindly request detailed documentation or guidance for configuring Ubuntu Landscape with Keycloak, specifically:

Confirming the correct redirect/callback URL format
Clarifying any additional OpenID settings required in service.conf
Steps for debugging authentication failures between Landscape and Keycloak


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This Q&A site is for Ubuntu users helping each other. It looks like you are looking for the official Ubuntu support from Canonical.
